# Como obter os parâmetros da linha de comando/caminho do arquivo?

Tags: c#, .net, parâmetros, linha-de-comando

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, e preciso por parâmetros/comandos junto do caminho do arquivo.

Por exemplo, estas *flags*:

```
C:/caminho_do_arquivo -r 

C:/caminho_do_arquivo -v
```

E no código teria regiões que identificariam esse comando, por exemplo.

```
switch url;
case r:

case v:
```

Mas não conheço nenhuma função que identifique tais parâmetros. Como faço para obtê-los?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem duas formas. Uma com parâmetro no `Main()`:

```
void Main(string[] args) {
    foreach(var arg in args) {
        switch(arg) {
            case "-r":
            //faz algo aqui
            case "-v":
            //faz algo aqui
        }
    }
}
```

E se não puder fazer no `Main()` e nem passar o que recebe dele para outro método, pode usar [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Environment_GetCommandLineArgs):

```
void Main() {
    var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    foreach(var arg in args) {
        switch(arg) {
            case "-r":
            //faz algo aqui
            case "-v":
            //faz algo aqui
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enviroment/CommandLIneVars.cs).

Pelo menos é isto de forma simplificada. Claro que é preciso validar melhor os dados recebidos. Dependendo do que vai pegar, se for algo além de *flags* pode ser preciso uma lógica mais complexa. Se você tiver certeza que terá apenas uma *flag*, pode simplificar retirando o laço do `foreach`. Mas lembre-se que isto é uma entrada de usuário, pode vir qualquer coisa maluca.

Existem algumas alternativas prontas mais poderosas:

- [NDesk.Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options) - Bem poderosa e flexível
- [Mono.Options](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Options/Mono.Options/Options.cs) - Dá para usar no .NET, é só incluir no seu projeto.
- [Command Line Parser Library](https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline) - Outra bem completa
- Daria para listar uma quantidade incomensurável de opções disponíveis de diversas bibliotecas e softwares públicos. Fica a dica para procurar uma pronta se tem alguma necessidade específica. Tem grande chance de alguém já ter o feito.

Comment: Bem é só um flag então obrigado. Quanto as entradas de usuário, sem problemas, afinal esse aplicativo é apenas para controle de versão, e não vai ir no deploy da mesma.

Comment: Apenas uma duvida. No evento de compilação "Pre-Build" como faço para por essa flag no caminho do arquivo?

Comment: @JoãoPauloPulga aqui mostra onde fica, na tela de debug http://csharp.2000things.com/2010/06/30/specify-command-line-arguments-in-visual-studio-2010/ (Command line arguments)

Comment: Dava uma nova pergunta :)

Comment: @Bacco gostaria de adicionar também no evento de compilação, pois essa flag também deve ser linda quando se da um Build no projeto. 
(Funcionaria do mesmo jeito, mas a solução tem quase 300 projetos.
E obrigado pela edição da pergunta. Ficou muito melhor :p)